# How does Java find a specification implementation?

Tags: java, specifications

I don't understand how java knows an implementation of any spec..

For example, I have a Spring App with JSF, if I place the Mojarra jar on classpath the app works, but I have not done nothing but that add it to classpath, all without configuration

If I take out the Mojarra jar, then my app doesn't works.

Even, How it can differenciate between Mojarra or MyFaces without any change?

I just want to know how Java finds the implementations, not why it doesn't work if I take out the jars ;)

Comment: Java just looks for the class name to load. It checks its build path and works through all the jar files and other libraries until its finds an implementation of the class file its looking for.

Comment: @MaheshGuruswamy post an answer maybe?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I did post an answer. Its a hint for the OP to look up class loading and how it works in Java.

Comment: @MaheshGuruswamy I don't see an answer with you as author, only a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen the mojarra jar (JSF Reference Implementation) and I found that it uses The Service Loader API, since it places the javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer, javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension and com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider inside the /META-INF/services folder in the javax.faces-2.2.0.jar.

This is how java distinguishes between an implementation and another (mojarra or myfaces).

Answer (score 2):

Usually the Java spec classes are divided in two parts:

1. An API part(jar) that contains mainly interfaces usually provided by the spec guys.
2. An implementation part(jar) that contain the implementations of these interfaces.

An example of the above is JDBC: `javax.sql.*` classes are provided by `sun/oracle`, but the implementation is done in the JDBC drivers provided by each db vendor. In this case some kind of configuration is needed in order to "map" the API to its implementation because you use `API` classes only.

Your example with `JSF` is a little different in that both `Mojarra` and `MyFaces` contains the `API` classes from `javax.faces.*` package, basically there are different classes with the same names. So there is no need for configuration, the classes have the same name in both libraries and are loaded by the class loader whenever needed from the `Mojarra` or `MyFaces` jars whichever is on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks @dcernahoschi, but I want to know how the 'map' is done, because if I place the mojarra jar or myfaces jar, each one of them have differents implementations class names, thus how java read the javax.jsf.Impl1 or javax.jsf.other.Impl2 ???

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well: in case of Mojarra and MyFaces the classes (although different) have the same names, no need for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I have found MyFaces and Mojarra Implementation for JSF. I have realized that both has same pachage structure so it means that all are compliance with JSF spec. In other word which implementation jar is given into classpath classpath loader will handle it.

It is all about Java Class Loader mechanism of JVM. You can find detailed discussion at Java Class Loaders

**Here is the picture of both JSF implemantation package structure.**

[image]